# How to configure compose key in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, compose-key

I frequently use the compose key to type special characters. I now have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, and in the keyboard settings it says "compose key: disabled". I can't find how to set the compose key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to install dconf Editor from the Ubuntu Software Centre so it will appear in your applications.

If you use an applications list it appears under Sundry or if not in your Activities Overview (type dconf in the ~type to search~ box).

There are other ways of achieving your aim but this is a simple gui method not needing terminal skills.

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:{key}']"
```

where `{key}` is your chosen key-name (*e.g.* `"['compose:ralt']"` would make right alt your compose key.

Comment: u bent van harte welkom. veel succes

Comment: This is crazy; why did they go backwards on the (very convenient) compose key? Update: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1245064

Comment: You don't "need" to install `dconf-editor` just for this purpose. See the answer from @lovestha below.

Comment: For completeness of this answer (mentioned in other answer): xkboptions can be found at `org > gnome > desktop > input-sources`. Options for key can be found in the manpage for `xkeyboard-config`, which can be found by typing `man xkeyboard-config` in a terminal, or in this page: http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=XKEYBOARD-CONFIG&ampsect=7. Search for "Compose key" (which can be done in the terminal manpage by pressing `/` and then typing your query, followed by enter).

Comment: -1 for answer. All job have done by @DaanWilmer, who gave precise path for this option in dconf-editor.

Comment: The answer from @LovesTha below is so much simpler.

Comment: @DavidDossot simpler *if and only if* you want to choose your compose key from that 6 given. because FU, thats why.

Comment: @törzsmókus True that.

Answer (score 40):

In keyboard settings -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Compose Key

Click the 'Disabled' across from Compose Key and select the key you want.

Comment: Not sure why it took someone so long to post the easiest solution. Absolutely no need to use `dconf-editor` to setup hotkeys. +1

Comment: I think it took so long because when I asked this question, this didn't work. Or I wouldn't have asked the question. Now it does work on my computer, so the question is kind of obsolete. btw, how do I find out why my question gave me negative points?

Comment: The downside of this is that not every key is available: right ctrl/alt/win, left ctrl, menu, or caps lock. I, for one, prefer the Scroll Lock key to be the compose key.

Comment: @ElefantPhace This is definitely a nicer option, but at least the accepted answer has the benefit that it will probably work even after another interface change (which wouldn't surprise me since, after all, it's not really clear at all why *the position of a key* would be considered a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading from 12 where I had both Caps Lock and Right Alt as compose keys. Looks like that's no longer an option with this UI.

Comment: *the key I want* is not there among the options. what a stupid idea that I cannot choose any key.

Comment: My initial problem was I could not uncheck the "disabled". I can now.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu 14.04

```
Sundry → dconf → org → gnome → desktop → input-sources → xkboptions
```

e.g. to set the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key as compose:

```
['compose:ralt']
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I need more help. The only "Sundry" I can find is a file named X-GNOME-Sundry.directory but it doesn't contain a directory name.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the dconf editor, select the down pointing triangles in this order: org, desktop, input-sources all within the left pane. Each of these expands a menu where you can select the next option. After you pick input-sources, you will see the xkboptions in the right panel, select that and you can enter your choice as outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the "disabled" and choose any of the available keys in the appeared drop-down list. Than you can hit the key and type key combinations. For example

```
<Key> o / gives ø symbol. 
<Key> . . gives … symbol
<Key> a ' gives à
```

and so one