# How to type a section sign (§) into the Minecraft client

Tags: keyboard, games, minecraft

So in Minecraft, the section sign (§) can be useful to make colors in text and so on. However, I can't seem to type it.  I've tried pasting the character in using Ctrl-V as well as middle mouse. I've even tried using `xdotool type "§"`, but it just doesn't register, even though using `xdotool type "foobar"` will work. Is Minecraft perhaps just filtering out that character or something on Linux?

**Update:** I found out that the Minecraft **client** doesn't accept the § symbol for generating color/style sequences in text. The use of those sequences is for the server only. However, I did find out that in recent versions that if you want to change the color of text on a sign, you just apply dye to it, which is what I wanted to use the sequences for anyways.

Comment: Find out the utf code for that character and use ctrl shift u shortcut. See https://askubuntu.com/a/364/295286

Comment: @Serg Its codepoint is A7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to type special characters in the terminal you need to use the `compose key`

[To configure the `compose` key on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/453331/650195), you need to [install dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it) and you can find the setting
[in the package `dconf/org/gnome/desktop/input-source/xkboptions`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Bxz.png)

> From Ubuntu 14.04

```
dconf → org → gnome → desktop → input-sources → xkboptions
```

> e.g. to set the Alt Gr key as compose:

```
['compose:ralt']
```

Then [you can use the `compose` key to type that special character](https://superuser.com/a/59573/693836).

> By pressing Compose, some key, some key… in sequence, you can input characters. I have my compose key set to Menu; to type a `©` (copyright symbol), I would use Menu, o, c.
>
> A full list of X compose key combinations [can be found online](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre) (200 KiB), or locally in /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.

The character "§" is included in the below list

```
XCOMM Other symbols
<Multi_key> <s> <o>                 : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <o> <s>                 : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <S> <O>             : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <O> <S>             : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <s> <exclam>        : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <S> <exclam>        : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_pe> <Cyrillic_a>  : "§"   section # SECTION SIGN
```

The other option is typing the [`Unicode` character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash) as suggested from [**Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy**](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy).

The [unicode character is available in this table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful answer, it turns out that the Minecraft client just doesn't accept that symbol intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Making an answer out of [@SergiyKolodyazhnyy's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138696/how-to-type-a-section-sign-into-the-minecraft-client/1423800#comment1887098_1138696):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> together.
- Then press <kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>7</kbd> (the UTF-8 code point of the § character).
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That should get you the §.